# Removing metal tabs on Lutron dimmer switch in ganged box

Tags: dimmer-switch

We have a two device switch box with a light switch (large switch style) and a dimmer switch. The dimmer switch stopped working, and so I plan to install a new Lutron dimmer switch instead. I haven't taken off the front cover plate yet, but I have a general question.

It says in the instructions that in a two-gang setup to remove the metal tabs on the side of the dimmer switch that will be next to the other switch so that it will fit. But I know that some switches are narrower than others. If there is room for me to install the new dimmer switch without removing the metal tabs, should I remove the tabs anyway or keep them on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimmer will fit without touching any part of the other switch it's OK and advisable to leave the tabs in place since removing them will decrease the capacity of the dimmer @Harper thanks. Personally, I'd remove them if you're installing a few low wattage bulbs now just in case you add a larger switch in the future and maybe forget about the removable tabs on the dimmer. Then you'd have to come back here and ask how to make the switch fit in the box. :-)

Comment: Except there's a consequence to removing them: it reduces the capacity of the dimmer and makes it run hotter.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Good point . I forgot about that since I've always over sized dimmers  and broke up the light circuits.

Comment: Thanks. The switch controls 4 light bulbs. The most plausible wattage that it'd need is 4x70 watts, but it's highly unlikely we'd ever actually use that much. But even still I wouldn't want it running hotter, so I'll just see if it would get too close to the other switch and decide.

Comment: To follow up though, you said if it can fit without touching then it's okay to leave the tabs in place. Is it a matter of *touching* even if it would fit? Because the illustration in the instructions made it look like when removing the tabs in a ganged box, the switches would fit snugly side by side. Would it be okay for them to touch side by side in that situation?

Comment: @AL  Yes, they can touch side by side.  You just don't want them overlapping because  then the cover plate won't fit right.

Comment: @JACK Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: @JACK Actually another follow up question. The answer and comments here would suggest that it's better to keep the tabs except for the fact that you need to have enough room. So is there a reason that Lutron makes them wider in the first place or why the removal of the fins by design reduces the wattage it can handle?

Comment: @AL The tabs are part of the heat sinks needed dissipate the heat from the dimmer. In a single gang box, they work great and can operate at full load. With the more up to date electronics in dimmers they need to dissipate more heat, so they're made wider. Once you start adding dimmers in every room and doubling them up in boxes, the tabs need to be removed to make room for the switches. This cuts down on the heat dissipation.  This isn't  too bad if using fluorescent or LED bulbs because the wattage is low but could cause overheating with incandescent bulbs because they generate  more heat.

Comment: @JACK Okay; thank you for the explanation!